How can I completely remove a Whatsapp conversation?
When I remove a conversation from Whatsapp, the session still exists: the name of the contact is still visible.
When I remove the contact from the "Contacts" app, the name of the contact is replaced by the telephone number, but I would like this to be removed too.
What can I do in order to do this?
Thanks in advance

Delete the contact from your contacts app //If it still shows up delete cache of both contacts app and WhatsApp

@beeshyams: thanks your your quick reply. Can you tell me how to clean the cache of an app on a smartphone?

@beeshyams: in the meantime I've removed the contact and cleared the cache of my Whatsapp but I still see the phone number. How can I remove this?

Did you clear the cache of contacts app also? Being a system app, it will not show up in your list of installed apps. From the 3 dot menu of apps list in your settings, usually you have an option to show system apps. From there go to contacts//Follow that up by forcing a re-sync of your contacts and WhatsApp

I've removed the contact, cleared the cache of the contacts app and cleared the cache of the Whatsapp app, but still the problem is not solved.

This is surprising //Go to accounts or passwords & Accounts on your phone and locate the WhatsApp account. Tap on it and sync all and then check

Wait.. Before you do that easier would be to open WhatsApp and you will find the big + in blue. Tap that and from 3 buttons menu on top right - refresh (it should say contacts updated) and then check//

Could you clarify by "the name of the contact is still visible"? Is it still visible on the chat list, or WhatsApp's contact list? Otherwise, by "the session still exists", did you mean you want to delete the chat? If that's what you want, then from the chat list, long-press the chat and tap the trash icon on the top menu. I'd assume you used "Clear chat" from the in-chat menu?

@AndrewT.: when I look at my Whatsapp, I still see the phone number (as explained in my last edit), I'd like this to be removed too.
